# Wordpress set value from input field as comment author for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a shared account, lets call it "marketing".
Now I have three people using this account named Anna, Ben and Max.

When someone logs into this account and wants to type a comment with their name, it always shows the name "marketing" as author. How can I change this so that I put a name in my input field and I get the value from this as my comment author. In my comments.php I do not check if the user is logged on and call it here:

```
<input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2"/>
```

I tried to make following in my functions.php:

```
function change_author( $commentdata ) {
    if ( $commentdata['user_ID'] == 2 ) {  // User ID for Marketing

    $commentdata['user_ID'] = 0; 
    $commentdata['comment_author'] = '';

  }

  return $commentdata;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'change_author' );
```

In this case my comment_author will always be Anonymous and also if I set it to `NULL`.

When i give the variable a value `$commentdata['comment_author'] = 'test';`
I get "test" as my comment_author but as I said, I would like to have the value I set in my input field. It works for not logged in users very well so I thought there might be a trick for logged in users as well.

In phpMyAdmin I checked for the entries in the database and it is giving me the right values for ID etc. But it also empties the comment_author field which results in an anonymous author.

I really hope that somebody can give me the right hint to accomplish this task.

Comment: I don't think WP is designed for that. Why don't you just set a new user role called 'Marketing' with the same rights and then create 3 users having this role ?

Comment: If I wanted to do exactly that I would have done that. No it is like an Intranet but I only provided an example. I just want this one user for all. I know it is not best practice but would be the best for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goddamit, I didn't know that this was so f***ing easy.

```
function change_author( $commentdata ) {

    if ( $commentdata['user_ID'] == 2 ) { 

    $commentdata['user_ID'] = 0;
    $commentdata['comment_author'] = $_POST['author'];
    $commentdata['comment_author_email'] = '';
    $commentdata['comment_author_url'] = '';

  }

  return $commentdata;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'change_author' );
```

I think this would work also with `!= 0` instead of `== 2`.
This is just a solution for my custom theme but I think it would also work with

```
$commentdata['comment_author_email'] = $_POST['mail'];
$commentdata['comment_author_url'] = $_POST['url'];
```

> Note: the value in $_POST[] is either the name or the ID from the
>   input field. Didn't test everything because name and ID have the same
>   value in my theme.

Tested it a few times local and it worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/ this plugin might help you, you can have multiple accounts under one account.

Comment: I already have this plugin installed. Unfortunately I used it for another problem and it does not solve my question I have now. I do not want multiple accounts I just want one where I can give any name I want for comments. And the question is: Is it possible to get the value from my field and read it out inside the function? Or not?

Comment: You can use custom field in that case, try advanced custom field plugin OR you can go with default wordpress custom field

Comment: I really think you did not understand my question. But doesn't matter, I already have a solution posted. Feel free to use and understand it.